# ServerSocket in Java programming

Tags: java

I am creating a client-server program in java using Socket and ServerSocket. My question is that can ServerSocket accept more than one request from different client with different port.

For Example

```
     ServerSocket soc1 = new ServerSocket(8001);
     ServerSocket soc1 = new ServerSocket(8002);
```

I want to use soc1 for both the port.

Thanks

Comment: you need to thread the thing. for every connection you open up a new socket and free soc1 for a new connection.
search for multi thread socket.

Comment: I think you're missing the entire point of ServerSocket.  ServerSocket permits you to listen for connections and then hand off the connections to worker threads once they're established.  What would be the use case of having ServerSocket listening to multiple ports, when you can simply have multiple server sockets each listening to one port each?

Comment: NO! you need separated references for each port.

Comment: No, and if you had two ports which did the same thing you wouldn't need too ports in the first place, just use one.

Answer (score 0):

no,it won't work as you image.
     ServerSocket soc1 = new ServerSocket(8001);
it return a Reference to soc1 which listening port 8001,
     ServerSocket soc1 = new ServerSocket(8002);
it return another Reference to soc1 which listening port 8002,
the old vaule of soc1 will be cover,at the same time,define Variables repeatty is not allowed.